# After setting up postgres and app service in docker-compose the Postgres is not reachable

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup a multi service docker environment for a Hanami web app using Postgres as a DB. I'm following Docker and other resources to do so. I currently have two service: postgres and app. I pan to add a separate one for nginx. After I run `docker-compose up` everything "seems" to be ok, but after I visit the url in my local browser I get the error about Postgres.

Here are all the details per each file:

EDIT 1>>>

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.5-bullseye

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install vim -y

# throw errors if Gemfile has been modified since Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle config --global frozen 1

RUN adduser --disabled-login app_owner

USER app_owner

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=app_owner Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
COPY --chown=app_owner . ./

RUN gem install bundler:1.17.3
RUN bundle install

ENV HANAMI_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV HANAMI_ENV=development

EXPOSE 2300

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "hanami", "server"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=some_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=some_pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=tmsr_development
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    #volumes: 
    #      - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec hanami server
    ports:
      - 2300:2300
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
#volumes:
#  db:
```

Startup log

```
Creating network "tmsr_default" with the default driver
Creating tmsr_db_1 ... done
Creating tmsr_web_1 ... done
Attaching to tmsr_db_1, tmsr_web_1
db_1   | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db_1   | This user must also own the server process.
db_1   | 
db_1   | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db_1   | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db_1   | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db_1   | 
db_1   | Data page checksums are disabled.
db_1   | 
db_1   | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db_1   | creating subdirectories ... ok
db_1   | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db_1   | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db_1   | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db_1   | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
db_1   | creating configuration files ... ok
db_1   | running bootstrap script ... ok
db_1   | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db_1   | syncing data to disk ... ok
db_1   | 
db_1   | 
db_1   | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1   | 
db_1   |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1   | 
db_1   | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1   | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1   | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1   | waiting for server to start....2022-01-18 06:44:49.111 UTC [49] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
db_1   | 2022-01-18 06:44:49.114 UTC [49] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2022-01-18 06:44:49.125 UTC [50] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-01-18 06:44:48 UTC
db_1   | 2022-01-18 06:44:49.131 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server started
db_1   | CREATE DATABASE
db_1   | 
db_1   | 
db_1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2022-01-18 06:44:49.343 UTC [49] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db_1   | waiting for server to shut down....2022-01-18 06:44:49.346 UTC [49] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db_1   | 2022-01-18 06:44:49.347 UTC [49] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 56) exited with exit code 1
db_1   | 2022-01-18 06:44:49.347 UTC [51] LOG:  shutting down
db_1   | 2022-01-18 06:44:49.369 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server stopped
db_1   | 
db_1   | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2022-01-18 06:44:49.474 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
db_1   | 2022-01-18 06:44:49.474 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2022-01-18 06:44:49.474 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2022-01-18 06:44:49.487 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2022-01-18 06:44:49.500 UTC [63] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-01-18 06:44:49 UTC
db_1   | 2022-01-18 06:44:49.510 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1  | Puma starting in single mode...
web_1  | * Puma version: 5.5.2 (ruby 2.7.5-p203) ("Zawgyi")
web_1  | *  Min threads: 0
web_1  | *  Max threads: 5
web_1  | *  Environment: development
web_1  | *          PID: 1
web_1  | * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:2300
web_1  | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Error

```
Boot Error

Something went wrong while loading /usr/src/app/config.ru
Hanami::Model::Error: PG::ConnectionBad: 
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) 
and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: 
Cannot assign requested address Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

<<<EDIT 1

EDIT 2>>>

I've compared the terminal output when running via docker or plain server start from my app root.

Docker output:

```
web_1  | * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:2300
```

App server output on local machine:

```
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:2300
* Listening on http://[::1]:2300
```

Might this be the issue?

Comment: Please provide all the necessary information in the question itself. Links to external resources can expire, at which time the question becomes useless to future readers.

Comment: I apologize for providing only a gist. Full content is now in the question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not refer to your connection as `localhost`

```
Cannot assign requested address Is the server running on host "localhost"
```

from your app reference the container name `db`
you are working inside docker which have it's own network so when you use `localhost` you are referencing the host network which your app isn't running on

Comment: True, thank you for the hint. I had to change the reference in my DB URL in app .env.